# Writing makefile to compile several binaries

Tags: build, makefile, build-process, gnu-make

I am trying to write a Makefile to compile 87 files with the following names:
    file1.c, file2.c file3.c .... file87.c

I am trying to compile them into separate binaries with names:
    file1, file2, file3 .... file87

In the Makefile I need to define following variables for each and every one of them. **This is what I had originally**.

```
FILE1 = file1
$(FILE1)_SRC := \
        mydir/file1.c \
        mydir/another.c

$(FILE1)_CFLAGS := `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`
$(FILE1)_LDFLAGS := -L. `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`

FILE2 = file2
$(FILE2)_SRC := \
        mydir/file2.c \
        mydir/another.c

$(FILE2)_CFLAGS := `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`
$(FILE2)_LDFLAGS := -L. `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```

Also at the end of the Makefile I need to store the names of the binaries

```
binaries = $(FILE1) $(FILE2) ...... $(FILE87)
```

I explored loops and define directive in make but I cannot understand how can I do this neatly in a non-cumbersome manner. Please note the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS are same for all of them.

Any inputs or alternative approaches to writing the Makefile are very welcome.

**I wrote this based on seldon's answer below, but this gives an error**:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard mydir/*.c)
TGTS = $(SRCS:%.c=%)

CFLAGS  = $$(pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)
LDFLAGS = -L.
LDLIBS  = $$(pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)

all: $(TGTS)
    @echo $(SRCS)
    @echo $(TGTS)

$(TGTS) : % : %.o another.o

#clean:
 #   rm -f $(TGTS) *.o

#.PHONY: all clean

$ make
cc $(pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)   -c -o mydir/another.o mydir/another.c
make: *** No rule to make target `another.o', needed by `mydir/another'.  Stop.
```

Source:

another.c

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

void print_string(const char * file_name, int lineno, const char * func_name) {

    printf("%s %d %s\n", file_name, lineno, func_name);

}
```

file01.c

```
int main() {

    print_string(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you need `binaries` for?

Comment: @Beta, I need to build them. Thanks.

Comment: Read the error! It is _make_ complaining that you have not told it how to build `another.o`. Then look at your Makefile. The only line where `another.o` appears is the static pattern rule `$(TGTS) : % : %.o another.o`. If each target in `${TGTS}` does not depend on `another.o`, then take it out! (just the dependency, not the whole line!)

Comment: @bobbogo Actually from the source that I posted each file*.c needs another.c for compilation.

Answer (score 3):

If the variables are the same for all programs, you could use a static pattern rule like this:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard file*.c)
TGTS = $(SRCS:%.c=%)

CFLAGS  = $$(pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)
LDFLAGS = -L.
LDLIBS  = $$(pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)

all: $(TGTS)

$(TGTS) : % : %.o another.o

clean:
    rm -f $(TGTS) *.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the error please ? I also posted the sources. Thanks.

Comment: Static pattern rules are definitely the way to go, Yay! (Really don't like the _wildcard_ call though, Boo!)

Comment: Make it `$(wildcard mydir/file*.c)` to explicitly exclude `another.c` from `$(TGTS)`, and `$(TGTS) : % : %.o mydir/another.o` so `mydir/another.c` is compiled into everything. If you want to place the Makefile into a different directory than the source, the paths become important.

Comment: @seldon I will try that, thanks. Also what is this line doing? `$(TGTS) : % : %.o mydir/another.o` Can you please explain what is the code telling/doing? Why empty %?

Comment: @bobbogo Can you please show me what you have in mind to use use static pattern rules ?

Comment: @abc I was merely congratulating @seldon on his (her?) use of a static pattern rule. Please see the manual http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern. (In your case you have told _make_ to expect `another.c`, but you don't have one of those. You only have `mydir/another.c` seemingly (I'm guessing here).)